# The love2d game.exe is not sharp in windows. How to make the game sharp(for pixel game)?

Tags: lua, game-development, love2d

[image: pic for game in windows] In windows

[image: pic for game in linux] In linux

I am a linux user so i was making the game in linux. While developing the game when i compiled the game, it was sharp. For sharping i have used this code `love.graphics.setDefaultFilter('nearest', 'nearest')`.

After completing the game i have made it executable for windows in both 32 and 64 bit. On running the .exe file in windows, it is not as sharp as it is showing in linux. The game works fine but, this small detail is bugging my mind. Any suggessions?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [conf.lua](https://love2d.org/wiki/Config_Files) and play around with the `t.window.msaa` option.